# How to draw hyperbola using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can some one help me to draw hyperbola using JavaScript.As i am able to draw parabola now. but in hyperbola getting confused. For parabola i used:

```
function drawParabola(y)
            {

                 myGraph.context.clearRect(0, 0, myGraph.canvas.width, myGraph.canvas.height);
                 myGraph = new Graph({
                    canvasId: "myCanvas",
                    minX: -10,
                    minY: -10,
                    maxX: 10,
                    maxY: 10,
                    unitsPerTick: 1
                });

                myGraph.drawEquation(function(x){
                    return y*x*x;
                }, "red", 2);
            }
```

Please suggest me for hyperbola

Comment: For an hyperbola, you can't have `y=fun(x)`, you need to draw lines between successive points (x, y).

Comment: @dystroy y=1/x is a hyperbola.

Comment: @geekchic there is only **one** hyperbola, the rectangular one, which may be defined as y=f(x)...